# spring conditional feature enabling

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

For this question, say, we have a MVC configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
      return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   }
   // bla-bla

}
```

I have several bean definitions as usual in a configuration class. The question is while enabling some features such as `@EnableCaching`, `@EnableMBeanExport`, `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`, how can i control enabling process of those features, ie:

```
@Configuration
// @EnableCaching instead of this
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

   @Autowired
   SomeResource someResource;

   @Bean
   public SomeBean someBean() {
      if(someResouce.someEvaluation(someParam)) {
         enableCaching();   // is that enabling possible?
      }
   }

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
      return new InternalResourceViewResolver();
   }
   // bla-bla

}
```

*NOTE:* I'm using spring 3.2.x

Comment: I hardly dare to say but how about Spring Boot instead of rolling your own. Spring 4 comes with conditional beans you might want to check those.

Comment: Maybe use spring profiles to include/exclude additional config files?

Comment: @Nadir Could you provide a concrete example?

Comment: Take a look here http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2012/06/12/spring-3-1-environment-profiles/ there is a example how to enable specific profile while evaluating some params in ApplicationContextInitializer class